# syntax for inserting hstore arrays in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, hstore

New to Postgres, just wondering how the syntax would be like. For example, I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  field1 hstore[],
  field2 text[],
  field3 hstore
)
...
```

For inserting arrays, syntax is like

```
INSERT INTO test (field2)  VALUES (' {"abc","def"} ');
```

and for inserting hstore, syntax is like

```
INSERT INTO test (field3) VALUES (' "a"=>1.0, "b"=>2.4 ');
```

but,,, for insertions on '**field1**', what do I do? Something like below gives me errors:

```
INSERT INTO test (field1) 
VALUES (`{'"a"=>1.0, "b"=>2.0', '"a"=>3.0, "b"=>4.0' }`)
```

Any fixes? Thanks!

==EDIT==

---

Just figured it out.

```
INSERT INTO test (field1) 
VALUES ('{"a=>1.0, b=>2.0", "a=>3.0, b=>4.0"}' )
```

The answer below helps as well, but in this particular case, a string(instead of an Array structure) works better with my existing code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll have a much easier time with the [array constructor syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT):

> The `ARRAY` constructor syntax can also be used:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO sal_emp
>     VALUES ('Bill',
>     ARRAY[10000, 10000, 10000, 10000],
>     ARRAY[['meeting', 'lunch'], ['training', 'presentation']]);
> ```

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO test (field1) 
VALUES (array['"a"=>1.0, "b"=>2.0'::hstore, '"a"=>3.0, "b"=>4.0'::hstore]);
```

You only need the `::hstore` cast on the first element in the array but it doesn't hurt to cast them all.

I tend to use the array constructor syntax exclusively because all the string parsing and quoting gives me a headache.

If you can't use the array constructor syntax, you can ask PostgreSQL itself how to do it:

```
=> select array['"a"=>1.0, "b"=>2.0'::hstore, '"a"=>3.0, "b"=>4.0'::hstore];
                                array                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"\"a\"=>\"1.0\", \"b\"=>\"2.0\"","\"a\"=>\"3.0\", \"b\"=>\"4.0\""}
```

Note that the individual hstores are wrapped in double quotes:

```
"\"a\"=>\"1.0\", \"b\"=>\"2.0\""
```

and that they use backslash-escaped double quotes for their internal structure. That gives us:

```
INSERT INTO test (field1) 
VALUES ('{"\"a\"=>\"1.0\", \"b\"=>\"2.0\"","\"a\"=>\"3.0\", \"b\"=>\"4.0\""}');
```

I'd still try to use the array constructor syntax, all those nested quotes and escapes are nasty.

Comment: Thanks! this helps! It would be ideal to have just a string here instead of an 'Array' structure. I have some existing code which requires a string.

Comment: Have a look at my update. It is possible but it is a bit of a horrific mess.

Comment: ^ Thanks! Just figured out, I threw away the inner double quotes and it suddenly worked. Just by looking at your update, I believe it would work as well!

Comment: The hstore-quotes are usually only needed with "odd looking" keys. But, if you're generating all this stuff programatically, you'd want to throw in all the quotes and escaping and whatnot just in case.